# ReactiveUI command unsubscription

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, reactiveui

I have 2 Views and 2 ViewModels:

First View:

```
public partial class FirstView : Page
{
    FirstViewModel ViewModel;
    public FirstView()
    {
        ViewModel = new FirstViewModel();
        ViewModel.ShowSecondView.Subscribe(_ =>
        {              
            NavigationService.Navigate(new SecondView(ViewModel.ChildViewModel));
        });            

        this.DataContext = ViewModel;
        InitializeComponent();            
    }        
}
```

First ViewModel:

```
public class FirstViewModel
{
    SecondViewModel ChildViewModel;
    public ReactiveCommand<Unit, Unit> ShowSecondView { get; set; }
    public FirstViewModel()
    {
        ChildViewModel = new SecondViewModel();
        ShowSecondView = ReactiveCommand.Create(() => 
        {
             ChildViewModel.Reconfigure(...);  
        });          
    }        
}
```

Second View:

```
public partial class SecondView : Page
{
    SecondViewModel ViewModel;
    public SecondView(SecondViewModel viewModel)
    {
        ViewModel = viewModel;
        ViewModel.GoBack.Subscribe(_ => 
        {
            DoSomethingHard();
            if(NavigationService != null)  NavigationService.GoBack();
        });
        this.DataContext = ViewModel;
        InitializeComponent();            
    }        
}
```

Second ViewModel:

```
public class SecondViewModel
{
    public ReactiveCommand<Unit, Unit> GoBack { get; set; }
    public FirstViewModel()
    {
        VeryLongInitialization();
        GoBack = ReactiveCommand.Create(() => { });          
    }        
    public void Reconfigure(...)
    { ... }
}
```

So, when I run `FirstViewModel.ShowSecondView` several times and run `SecondViewModel.GoBack` several times, `DoSomethingHard()` execute also several times on each created SecondView.

Why do I want create `ChildViewModel` in `FilstViewModel` once? Because creating of `SecondViewModel` takes long time. And I don't recreate every time `SecondViewModel` but only reconfigure it.

My question is how can I unsubscribe `ViewModel.GoBack.Subscribe` in `SecondView`?

P.S. Maybe I should not recreate `SecondView` in `FirstView` but reconfigure it as well as `SecondViewModel`?

**UPDATE 1** (thanks to Julien Mialon)

I add `IDisposable goBackSubscr` and it works! Am I right to implement it?

```
public partial class SecondView : Page
{
    SecondViewModel ViewModel;
    IDisposable goBackSubscr;
    public SecondView(SecondViewModel viewModel)
    {
        ViewModel = viewModel;
        goBackSubscr = ViewModel.GoBack.Subscribe(_ => 
        {
            DoSomethingHard();
            if(NavigationService != null)  NavigationService.GoBack();
            goBackSubscr.Dispose();
        });
        this.DataContext = ViewModel;
        InitializeComponent();            
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Krzysztof Skowronek

I once again read about IViewFor and resolve my problem

```
public partial class SecondView : Page, IViewFor<SecondViewModel>
{
    public SecondViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }
    object IViewFor.ViewModel { get => ViewModel; set { ViewModel = (SecondViewModel)value; } }
    public SecondView(SecondViewModel viewModel)
    {
        ViewModel = viewModel;
        this.WhenActivated(disposables =>
        {
            ViewModel.GoBack.Subscribe(_ =>
                {
                    DoSomethingHard();
                    if (NavigationService != null) NavigationService.GoBack();
                })
                .DisposeWith(disposables);               

            this.WhenAnyValue(p => p.ViewModel)
                .BindTo(this, x => x.DataContext)
                .DisposeWith(disposables);
        });        
    InitializeComponent();            
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use [WhenAcitvated](https://reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/when-activated/) on your view:
in constructor of your page (it has to be IViewFor):

```
 this.WhenActivated(
     disposables =>
     {
         ViewModel.Command.Subscribe(...).(disposables);
     });
```

Comment: I read about IViewFor, but I don't understand it (absolutely)

Answer (score 2):

The subscribe method return an IDisposable, you should store it and dispose it when you want to unsubscribe.

Comment: I added UPDATE1 to question

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what you are trying to do. If I am right, you are trying to create a Wizard of some sort or something that displays one view model that can move to the next, and then that can move prior? If that sis the case then maybe you want to re-think how you are doing it.
For example, Why not manage the back and forth buttons in a view model that houses the two view models and have the child view models only create once when they are first required. Then, your navigation buttons can determine which view models are currently on and be enabled depending upon the logic. 
In a Wizard type scenario, consider basing your child view models on a Base view model that may have a property or method called something like CanMoveNext() and CanMovePrior(). Internally, this can return true if it is ready. Much easier.

Comment: No? it's not wizard. It's one-window-app with page navigation. For example, FirstViewModel is list of items and SecondViewModel is item's editor

Answer (score 0):

I would also recommend to enable and disable the commands with the activations and deactivations of the ViewModel.

Using a small helper:

```cs
    public static class DisabledCommand
    {
        public static readonly ReactiveCommand<Unit, Unit> Instance
            = ReactiveCommand.Create<Unit, Unit>(_ => Unit.Default, Observable.Return(false));
    }
```

You can do it like this:

```cs
public sealed class MyViewModel : ReactiveObject, IActivateableViewModel
{

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        this.WhenActivated(d =>
        {
            // Observable that returns boolean to define if button is enabled
            // ie. Observable.Create() or this.WhenAnyValue(...)
            var canDoSomething = ...;

            // enable command when VM gets activated
            DoSomething = ReactiveCommand.Create<Unit, Unit>(_ => Unit.Default, canDoSomething);

            // disable command when VM gets disabled
            Disposable.Create(() => DoSomething = DisabledCommand.Instance).DisposeWith(d);

            DoSomething
                .Select(_ => this) // select ViewModel
                .Do(vm =>
                { 
                    // ...
                })
                .ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
                .ExecuteOn(RxApp.TaskPoolScheduler)
                .Subscribe()
                .DisposeWith(d);
        });
    }

    [Reactive] public ReactiveCommand<Unit, Unit> DoSomething { get; set; } = DisabledCommand.Instance;
    public ViewModelActivator Activator { get; } = new ViewModelActivator();
}
```

Then in your view:

```cs
public partial class MyView : Page, IViewFor<MyViewModel>
{
    public MyView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.WhenActivated(d =>
        {
            if(ViewModel == null) return;

            IDisposable current = Disposable.Empty;
            ViewModel.WhenAnyValue(vm => vm.DoSomething)
                .Select(_ => ViewModel)
                .Subscribe(vm => 
                {
                    current.Dispose();
                    current = vm.DoSomething
                        .Select(_ => vm)
                        .Do(vm_ =>
                        {
                            // do something on the UI
                        })
                        .ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
                        .SubscribeOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
                        .Subscribe();
                })
                .ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
                .SubscribeOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
                .Subscribe()
                .DisposeWith(d);

              Disposable.Create(() => current.Dispose()).DisposeWith(d);
        });
    }

    object IViewFor.ViewModel
    {
        get => ViewModel;
        set => ViewModel = value as MyViewModel;
    }

    public MyViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get => DataContext as MyViewModel;
        set => DataContext = value;
    }
}
```